Is いいえ considered a rude word when rejecting an offer?
I have observed that there is a tendency to say はい or ええ, along with the rest of the reply when accepting an offer:

A: いっしょにテニスをしませんか。
B: はい、しましょう。

while there appears (to me, at least) to be some reluctance with いいえ (of course not by itself, I think that would be kind of rude in any culture), so that less straightforward expressions are used, such as いいです, 大丈夫です or 結構です. I sometimes see them preceded by いいえ, as in

A: 私がしましょうか。
B: いいえ、結構です。

But in many other situations I see just the reply without いいえ, like:

Waiter: もう少しいかがですか。
Customer: もう結構です。

Other times just 結構です without anything else. So I wonder if there is any nuance to it, or probably it depends on the context - say - it's rude for food but not for another kind of offer. Please mind that I'm just a beginner, so I don't have a good knowledge of 敬語. Please tell me if I should worry about such things and I could come across as rude.

While いいえ frequently appears in textbooks as the corresponding translation for "No", it's actually not a common word in everyday Japanese conversation. Apart from when playing "yes/no" quizzes or such, I personally say いいえ clearly only a few times a year. When used, it carries a rather formal and definitive "NO" connotation, and it can be harsh when turning down casual offers or requests.
いえ and いや are much milder and safer alternatives to いいえ in everyday business speech and interactions with locals.
Additionally, 大丈夫です and 結構です are indeed very common ways of turning down an offer without explicitly saying "no". Some beginners confuse these as meaning "Yes please", but they safely mean "No thanks" when used in appropriate situations.
